# JQuery event after twitter on complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if there was an event thrown after the twitter items are generated on the page. There is an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pborreli/pJgyu/). I cannot seem to get the `li` items to change after they are loaded. I have tried using [.ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/), but it doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone know what events are thrown after the above code, and that doesn't need user input? If you have time submit code it would also be much appreciated. You could you alter the above code and fork your own version. For ideas on examples that could be created; you could change all spaces to periods or periods to exclamation marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution, I was forced to go into the JQuery Twitter plugin, and add a trigger as shown below:

```
//Trigger once tweets returned
$(element).trigger("onTwitterComplete");
```

I then in my client code just bound to what was being thrown as shown below:
`$('#posts').tweets({username: "myusername"})
           .bind("onTwitterComplete",function(){/* ... */});`

Answer (score 0):

if your script is working page load event and your content bind comes on page dynamically then you have to put your script code at bottom of page.

As **li** element will bot found untill your page gets fully load.